# Is it possible to add foreign key between owned entities in EF Core 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, ef-core-6.0

I am trying to separate my contexts using DDD. I have two domains, `Instruments` and `Advertisements` with its aggregate roots (the example is hypothetical). `Instrument` AR owns many `InstrumentPicture`s and I would like to have that information in the `Advertisement` domain as well via proxy entity.

To ensure good database integrity it would be better to create foreign key from AdvertisementPicture.Guid to InstrumentPicture.Guid but as far as I know this can be done only through HasOne/HasMany model configuration.

Am I using the owner relationship wrong?

(Note: I do not want to configure the FK with custom sql migration.)

---

`Instrument` AR:

```
public class Instrument
{
    protected Instrument()
    {
    }

    public Instrument(string name, IEnumerable<InstrumentPicture> pictures)
    {
        Name = name;
        _instrumentPictures.AddRange(pictures);
    }

    protected List<InstrumentPicture> _instrumentPictures = new List<InstrumentPicture>();

    public IReadOnlyCollection<InstrumentPicture> InstrumentPictures
        => _instrumentPictures.AsReadOnly();

    public Guid Guid { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

---

`InstrumentPicture` owned collection:

```
public class InstrumentPicture
{
    protected InstrumentPicture()
    {
    }

    public InstrumentPicture(Guid guid, string url)
    {
        Guid = guid;
        Url = url;
    }

    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

---

`Advertisiment` AR

```
public class Advertisement
{
    protected Advertisement()
    {
    }

    public Advertisement(Guid instrumentGuid, string name, IEnumerable<AdvertisementPicture> pictures)
    {
        InstrumentGuid = instrumentGuid;
        Name = name;
        _advertisementPictures.AddRange(pictures);
    }

    protected List<AdvertisementPicture> _advertisementPictures = new List<AdvertisementPicture>();

    public IReadOnlyCollection<AdvertisementPicture> AdvertisementPictures
        => _advertisementPictures.AsReadOnly();

    public Guid Guid { get; private set; }
    public Guid InstrumentGuid { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

---

`AdvertisementPicture` proxy

```
public class AdvertisementPicture
{
    protected AdvertisementPicture()
    {
    }

    public AdvertisementPicture(Guid guid, string url)
    {
        Guid = guid;
        Url = url;
    }

    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

---

Model configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Instrument>()
        .HasKey(e => e.Guid);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Instrument>()
        .OwnsMany(e => e.InstrumentPictures, pic =>
        {
            pic.HasKey(e => e.Guid);
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Advertisement>()
        .HasKey(e => e.Guid);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Advertisement>()
        .HasOne<Instrument>()
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.InstrumentGuid);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Advertisement>()
        .OwnsMany(e => e.AdvertisementPictures, pic =>
        {
            pic.HasKey(e => e.Guid);
            // How can I add a foreign key to original InstrumentPicture for database integrity?
        });
}
```

Comment: In DDD each Domain should have its own data-model.  One for Instruments domain, and one for Advertisement domain.  They can both be deployed in the same physical database but should remain distinct logical databases.  I.E. No database-enforced FKs across the domain boundary.  You should be free to change the data-model in one domain without that being of concern to other domains.  Once you start coupling them with FKs then you lose the benefits of DDD.  Whether you should split databases or combine domains into a single domain is dependent upon your needs.

Comment: @NeilW Good point, I think I still need to shift my mindset to bound contexts. From practial point of view tho if I write an app and I know the domains will exist in the same database, I could gain some benefits from configuring the foreign keys. Do you think having the domains separate in code but tightly coupled in database could lead to some issues later?

Comment: Not necessarily.  But now you just have an application that is split into different 'modules / projects' (not bounded contexts), which is fine.  But it's no longer DDD.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for hours and finding lots of answers on SO saying this isn't possible. Turns out this is possible using EntityFrameworkCore so I'll post what I've found on my Top Google Search for this problem.

As soon as you add a foreign key you will find the migration tool attempting to create the table in the second DBContext (unless you add ModelBuilder.Ignore<>() which will either do nothing or ignore your foreign key depending on your order of operations).

You can however do something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
        .ToTable("AspNetUsers", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
}
```

This will allow you to reference tables in other DBContext's but exclude any changes to them from the one you're working in. This is outlined in the MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#excluding-parts-of-your-model).

If you have used Fluent API you may still need to apply those configurations in the referencing DB Context. This is easily achieved if you have used the `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` implementation by an additional call to `ModelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(T).Assembly);`.

In such a use case as above you may find yourself excluding a lot of different entities from your DB context. If you have these defined in their own library like I have to follow a DDD pattern you may find an extension method useful to exclude all of them at once:

```
public static class ExcludeEntitiesInAssemblyFromMigrationsExtension
    {
        public static void ExcludeEntitiesInAssemblyFromMigrations(this ModelBuilder builder, Assembly assembly)
        {
            var assemblyTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract);
            foreach (var assemblyType in assemblyTypes)
            {
                var entityBuilder = builder.Entity(assemblyType);
                var entityTablename = entityBuilder.Metadata.GetTableName();
                if (entityTablename != null)
                {
                    entityBuilder.ToTable(entityTablename, t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```